# Assertion failed Eigen debug mode

Tags: c++, eigen

I suddenly realized that when compiling my program (that uses Eigen) using debug mode (-g3 -DDEBUG), I am getting a runtime assertion error

```
Assertion failed: (v == T(Value)), function variable_if_dynamic, file /Users/vlad/eigen_3.2.2/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h, line 53
```

I cannot figure out where exactly is this happening and why. I also used    `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` in my only class that uses Eigen members, as I thought it may be an alignment issue, but still it doesn't solve the problem. Did anyone bumped into this before? The release version compiles and runs just fine, the assert appears only in debug mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not related to alignment, but to a mismatch between a compile-time and runtime value meaning you probably has something like this in your code:

```
Matrix<double,3,Dynamic> mat(4,5);
```

where the runtime number of rows `4` does not match the compile-time number of rows `3`. A debugger will help you to find the incriminating line.

Comment: Thanks much, will try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem